# Why do I keep getting `bash: local: command not found`

Tags: bash

Keep getting this error:

```
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   local: command not found
bash:   export: command not found
bash:   export: command not found
bash: ~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Here is my bash_profile:

When I comment out the prompt function, the error goes away except the last one!

```
alias ngrok=/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/ngrok

export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

alias ls='ls -GFh'

function prompt {
  local BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
  local BLACKBOLD="\[\033[1;30m\]"
  local RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
  local REDBOLD="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local GREENBOLD="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
  local YELLOWBOLD="\[\033[1;33m\]"
  local BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  local BLUEBOLD="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  local PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
  local PURPLEBOLD="\[\033[1;35m\]"
  local CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
  local CYANBOLD="\[\033[1;36m\]"
  local WHITE="\[\033[0;37m\]"
  local WHITEBOLD="\[\033[1;37m\]"
  local RESETCOLOR="\[\e[00m\]"

  export PS1="\n$RED\u $PURPLE@ $GREEN\w $BLUE[\#] → $RESETCOLOR"
  export PS2="| → $RESETCOLOR"
}

# prompt

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

source ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is being interpreted by `bash` and not another shell like `dash`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills how can I check?

Comment: `local` is a Bash builtins. Technically speaking, it can be disabled by writing `enable -n local` (and re-enabled by writing `enable local`), but it's odd that someone would do that. (And, similarly with `export`.)

Comment: How can I fix my problem though with that? Doesn't do any difference

Comment: Could also be that the commands are being led by non-breaking spaces rather than real whitespace; that would explain this behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `local` were genuinely not available (for instance, disabled with `enable -n local`), you would be seeing:

```
bash: local: command not found
```

Instead of:

```
bash:   local: command not found
```

---

Those extra spaces are a clue. Look closely at your file (with a hex editor, if you have to), and figure out what those bytes that aren't either spaces or tabs actually *are*... and change them to genuine ASCII space characters.

There are several non-breaking space variants found in Unicode; I'm guessing that they somehow got into your script. Copy-and-pasting code from the web can be dangerous. :)

Comment: Yes! It was a problem of spacing... I literally just fixed it and came here and saw your answer. Thanks!